# How to run two methods in Gradle in parallel mode?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I got a Gradle task which calls two methods. The methods are independent of each other so I want to start them parallel. What is the best way to achieve this?

Example:

```
task cucumber(dependsOn: 'testClasses') { 
    doLast {
        // ...
        // I want to call the next 2 methods in parallel
        runSequentialTests(testEnvironment, tags) 
        runParallelTests(testEnvironment, tags) 
    }
}

def runSequentialTests(testEnvironment, tags) {
    // execute cucumber tests via javaexec
}

def runParallelTests(testEnvironment, tags) {
    // execute cucumber tests via exec sh script for each feature file (parallelism is done via GParsPool.withPool(5) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worth researching groovy parallel systems library [gpars](http://www.gpars.org/webapp/guide/)

```
GParsPool.withPool {
    GParsPool.executeAsyncAndWait({runSequentialTests(testEnvironment, tags)}, {runParallelTests(testEnvironment, tags)})
}
```

Or maybe create a [`@ParallelizableTask`](http://www.imlc.me/14749714760806.html)

But I'm not sure what version of gradle you are using. And parallel is/was an incubating feature.

And needs to run build with --parallel if those have no dependencies between themselves Gradle should run them independently.

Alternatively, you can specify a property in your `gradle.properties`

`C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\gradle.properties
org.gradle.parallel=true`

Answer (score 0):

I used the asynchronous invocations of GPars: http://www.gpars.org/webapp/guide/#_asynchronous_invocations

I got it to work with this. Thanks

```
GParsPool.withPool {
    GParsPool.executeAsyncAndWait({runSequentialTests(testEnvironment, tags)}, {runParallelTests(testEnvironment, tags)})
}
```